# When an array changes, push it to an array history array

Tags: javascript, arrays

ive simplified the code alot to make it easier but im making a game on a grid which keeps track of the players game pieces.

If its a 9x9 grid, the array will have 9 indexs, each containing 9 index's so i can refer to a point on the grid as array[x][y]. Every turn i want to store this placement in a grid history array.

Ive tried to use array.push each time but after 1 turn, if i view the history, all the grids are the same as the current one. I made a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate - https://jsfiddle.net/3rmwnuv5/

Code below here too:

```
  var stones = [['clear', 'clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear', 'clear']]

  var stoneHistory = [];

  stoneHistory.push(stones);

  stones[1][1] = 'black';

  stoneHistory.push(stones);

  stones[0][2] = 'white';

  stoneHistory.push(stones);

  console.log(stoneHistory);
```

Answer (score 0):

So i looked up how to do a deep array and did it through json stringify like below.

```
  var stones = [['clear', 'clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear', 'clear']]

  var stoneHistory = [];

  var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stones));
  stoneHistory.push(copy);

  stones[1][1] = 'black';

  var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stones));
  stoneHistory.push(copy);

  stones[0][2] = 'white';

  var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stones));
  stoneHistory.push(copy);

  console.log(stoneHistory);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var stones = [['clear', 'clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear', 'clear']]

  var stoneHistory = [];

  var val1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stones));
  stoneHistory.push(val1);

  stones[1][1] = 'black';

  var val2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stones));
  stoneHistory.push(val2);

  stones[0][2] = 'white';

console.log(stoneHistory);
```